# Expected value of general uniform order statistics

Tags: uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I know that if $X_k$ ~ $Unif(0,1)$ and is order statistics, then $E[X_k] = \frac{k}{n+1}$.

What's $E[X_k]$  for when $X_k$ ~ $Unif(a,b)$?

I think it's $a + \frac{k}{n+1}(b-a).$ Can someone confirm?

Comment: Recall that if $X\sim\mathrm U(a,b)$ then $X$ is equal in distribution to $a+(b-a)U$, where $U\sim\mathrm U(0,1)$.